# kvm and gcp clash - help!

Tags: package-management, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am a basically Linux-illiterate user of Ubuntu 19.04.
I just (September 19, 2019) did a normal update with aptitude, and got the following error:

```
dpkg: Error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017_5.0.0-1017.18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
attempt to overwrite '/usr/lib/libcpupower.so.5.0.0-1017', which is also included in package linux-gcp-tools-5.0.0-1017 5.0.0-1017.17
```

What should I do?  How dangerous is this?
The KVM package has been partly installed, and whenever I run aptitude it comes up with the same error.

```
sudo apt-get update –fix-missing
sudo dpkg –configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

didn't help, nor did `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, which was proposed by `sudo apt autoremove`.

The output of `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
beep @ Block: ~ $ sudo apt-get install -f
Package lists are read ... Ready
Tree of requirements is being built
The status information is read ... Ready
Requirements are corrected ... Ready
The following packages are installed automatically and are no longer needed:
  linux-headers-5.0.0-25 linux-headers-5.0.0-25-generic linux-image-5.0.0-25-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-25-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to delete them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
0 B / 5133 kB of archives must be collected.
After this operation, an additional 24.1 MB of disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y / N]    
(Database is being read ... 398849 files and folders currently installed.)
Unpacking ... / linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017_5.0.0-1017.18_amd64.deb is being prepared ...
Unpacking linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017 (5.0.0-1017.18) ... dpkg: Error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017_5.0.0-1017.18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 attempt to overwrite '/usr/lib/libcpupower.so.5.0.0-1017', which is also included in package linux-gcp-tools-5.0.0-1017 5.0.0-1017.17
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors found while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017_5.0.0-1017.18_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output of `sudo apt autoremove`:

```
biep@Blok:~$ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] wachtwoord voor biep: 
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd       
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar
U kunt 'apt --fix-broken install' uitvoeren om dit op te lossen.
De volgende pakketten hebben niet-voldane vereisten:
 linux-tools-5.0.0-1017-kvm : Vereisten: linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017 maar het is niet geïnstalleerd
E: Er zijn niet-voldane vereisten. U kunt best 'apt --fix-broken install' uitvoeren zonder pakketten op te geven, (of u kunt zelf een oplossing specificeren).
```

`sudo apt --fix-broken install` gives this:

```
biep@Blok:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd       
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar
Vereisten worden gecorrigeerd... Klaar
De volgende pakketten zijn automatisch geïnstalleerd en zijn niet langer nodig:
  linux-headers-5.0.0-25 linux-headers-5.0.0-25-generic linux-image-5.0.0-25-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-25-generic
Gebruik 'sudo apt autoremove' om ze te verwijderen.
De volgende extra pakketten zullen geïnstalleerd worden:
  linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017
De volgende NIEUWE pakketten zullen geïnstalleerd worden:
  linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017
0 opgewaardeerd, 1 nieuw geïnstalleerd, 0 te verwijderen en 0 niet opgewaardeerd.
1 niet volledig geïnstalleerd of verwijderd.
Er moeten 0 B/5133 kB aan archieven opgehaald worden.
Na deze bewerking zal er 24,1 MB extra schijfruimte gebruikt worden.
Wilt u doorgaan? [J/n] 
(Database wordt ingelezen ... 398849 bestanden en mappen momenteel geïnstalleerd.)
Uitpakken van .../linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017_5.0.0-1017.18_amd64.deb wordt voorbereid...
Bezig met uitpakken van linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017 (5.0.0-1017.18) ...
dpkg: fout bij verwerken van archief /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017_5.0.0-1017.18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 poging tot overschrijven van '/usr/lib/libcpupower.so.5.0.0-1017', wat ook in pakket linux-gcp-tools-5.0.0-1017 5.0.0-1017.17 zit
dpkg-deb: fout: subproces plakken werd gedood door signaal (Gebroken pijp)
Fouten gevonden tijdens verwerken van:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-kvm-tools-5.0.0-1017_5.0.0-1017.18_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please run `sudo apt-get update –fix-missing`, `sudo dpkg –configure -a`, and `sudo apt-get install -f` and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1175344/edit) your question if you are still having problems

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install -f` solely and post the output by [***editing your question***](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1175344/edit)

Comment: It seems this problem blocks autoremovals.  `sudo apt autoremove` refuses to autoremove.  Riot did update, though, so it seems not to block updates.

Comment: Please edit your question one more time with the output of `sudo apt autoremove`, I am fairly sure I know the issue but do not want to ask you to fix it until I am sure

Comment: @Kulfy:
The answer there was contested.  And `scala` is a user package, one that one can remove without damaging the system.  My packages seem to be kernel packages, with which I don't like to experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the complete solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176520/switch-to-azure-disables-mousepad-internet-usb). Simply purging the offending kernels works.

It turned out I had three more unwanted kernels: azure, aws, and lowlatency.  No idea how I got those - I am sure I never explicitly installed those.  Anyway - simply purging them, making sure to keep the generic one, did the trick.