# Switch to Azure disables mousepad, Internet, USB

Tags: boot, kernel, azure

For some background about my Ubuntu 19.04 system, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175344).

Just before Midnight (CET) yesterday I rebooted, and instead of "Generic", "Azure" booted.  This kernel did not recognise any USB, so I had no working mouse pad or Internet (and could not use any USB mouse either).
Through Grub I could still boot an older "Generic" kernel, which seems to work well.  How should I proceed now?

BTW, I have a fully encrypted hard drive.

`System profiles` shows this:

```
-Boots-
Wed Sep 25 10:07        : 5.0.0-29-generic
Wed Sep 25 09:51        : 5.0.0-1020-azure
Wed Sep 25 09:40        : 5.0.0-1020-azure
Wed Sep 25 08:51        : 5.0.0-1020-azure
Wed Sep 25 08:49        : 5.0.0-1020-azure
Wed Sep 25 08:47        : 5.0.0-1020-azure
Wed Sep 25 08:13        : 5.0.0-1020-azure
Tue Sep 24 23:15        : 5.0.0-1020-azure
Tue Sep 24 23:09        : 5.0.0-1020-azure
Thu Sep 12 09:53        : 5.0.0-27-generic
Thu Sep 5 11:17     : 5.0.0-27-generic
Tue Aug 20 12:15        : 5.0.0-25-generic
Tue Aug 13 12:24        : 5.0.0-23-generic
Tue Aug 6 13:16     : 5.0.0-23-generic
Mon Aug 5 11:20     : 5.0.0-23-generic
Sat Aug 3 10:39     : 5.0.0-23-generic
Fri Aug 2 00:31     : 5.0.0-23-generic
Wed Jul 31 17:23        : 5.0.0-21-generic
Tue Jul 30 19:51        : 5.0.0-21-generic
Tue Jul 30 09:22        : 5.0.0-21-generic
Tue Jul 30 01:54        : 5.0.0-21-generic
Mon Jul 29 23:11        : 5.0.0-21-generic
Mon Jul 29 21:31        : 5.0.0-13-generic
```

`dpkg` output:

```
biep@Blok:~$ dpkg -l | grep azure
ii  linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1020           5.0.0-1020.21                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific cloud tools for version 5.0.0-1020
ii  linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1020               5.0.0-1020.21                              all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.0.0
ii  linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1020                 5.0.0-1020.21                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 5.0.0-1020
ii  linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1020-azure             5.0.0-1020.21                              amd64        Linux kernel buildinfo for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1020-azure           5.0.0-1020.21                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific cloud tools for version 5.0.0-1020
ii  linux-headers-5.0.0-1020-azure               5.0.0-1020.21                              amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-5.0.0-1020-azure                 5.0.0-1020.21                              amd64        Signed kernel image azure
ii  linux-modules-5.0.0-1020-azure               5.0.0-1020.21                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1020-azure         5.0.0-1020.21                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-tools-5.0.0-1020-azure                 5.0.0-1020.21                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 5.0.0-1020
biep@Blok:~$ dpkg -l | grep kvm
ii  linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1017-kvm               5.0.0-1017.18                              amd64        Linux kernel buildinfo for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.0.0-1017-kvm                 5.0.0-1017.18                              amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-5.0.0-1017-kvm                   5.0.0-1017.18                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-kvm-headers-5.0.0-1017                 5.0.0-1017.18                              all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.0.0
ii  linux-modules-5.0.0-1017-kvm                 5.0.0-1017.18                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-tools-5.0.0-1017-kvm                   5.0.0-1017.18                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 5.0.0-1017
biep@Blok:~$ dpkg -l | grep gcp
ii  linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1017-gcp               5.0.0-1017.17                              amd64        Linux kernel buildinfo for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-gcp-headers-5.0.0-1017                 5.0.0-1017.17                              amd64        Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.0.0
ii  linux-gcp-tools-5.0.0-1017                   5.0.0-1017.17                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 5.0.0-1017
ii  linux-headers-5.0.0-1017-gcp                 5.0.0-1017.17                              amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-5.0.0-1017-gcp                   5.0.0-1017.17                              amd64        Signed kernel image GCP
ii  linux-modules-5.0.0-1017-gcp                 5.0.0-1017.17                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1017-gcp           5.0.0-1017.17                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-tools-5.0.0-1017-gcp                   5.0.0-1017.17                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 5.0.0-1017
```

Purging:

```
biep@Blok:~$ LANG=C sudo apt purge 'linux.*azure'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-extra-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1010-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1016-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-5.0.0-1011-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1020-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1008-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1008-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1014-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1010-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1016-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-5.0.0-1020-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1010-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-5.0.0-1012-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-5.0.0-1018-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-5.0.0-1004-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1016-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1011-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1008-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1010-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1011-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1016-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1010-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-signed-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1016-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1014-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-signed-image-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1008-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1012-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1006-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1020-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1004' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1006' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1008' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1010' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1011' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1012' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1014' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1016' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1018' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1020' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1011-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1011-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1018-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1004-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1012-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1018-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1004-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1010-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-5.0.0-1006-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1020-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1012-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1012-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1018-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1018-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1004-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1004-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1011-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1020-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1008-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-5.0.0-1014-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1006-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1011-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1012-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1018-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1004-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1020-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1004' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1006' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1008' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1010' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1011' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1012' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1014' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1016' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1018' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1020' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1020-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1006-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1012-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1004' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1006' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1008' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1010' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1011' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1012' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1014' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1016' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1018' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1020' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1010-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1018-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1016-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1004-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1014-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1006-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1014-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1020-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-5.0.0-1016-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-doc-5.0.0' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-tools' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-5.0.0-1008-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1011-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1006-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-azure-source-5.0.0' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1014-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1014-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1006-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1012-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1018-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1006-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1004-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-5.0.0-1010-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1008-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1016-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1008-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Note, selecting 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1014-azure' for regex 'linux.*azure'
Package 'linux-azure-doc-5.0.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-source-5.0.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1004' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1004' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1004' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1004-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1004-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1004-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-5.0.0-1004-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1004-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1004-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1004-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1004-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1006' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1008' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1010' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1011' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1012' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1014' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1016' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1018' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1006' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1008' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1010' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1011' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1012' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1014' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1016' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1018' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1006' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1008' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1010' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1011' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1012' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1014' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1016' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1018' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1006-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1008-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1010-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1011-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1012-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1014-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1016-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1018-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1006-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1008-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1010-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1011-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1012-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1014-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1016-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1018-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1006-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1008-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1010-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1011-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1012-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1014-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1016-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-5.0.0-1018-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-5.0.0-1006-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-5.0.0-1008-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-5.0.0-1010-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-5.0.0-1011-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-5.0.0-1012-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-5.0.0-1014-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-5.0.0-1016-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-5.0.0-1018-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1006-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1008-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1010-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1011-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1012-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1014-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1016-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1018-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-1020-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1006-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1008-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1010-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1011-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1012-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1014-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1016-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-5.0.0-1018-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1006-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1008-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1010-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1011-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1012-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1014-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1016-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1018-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-extra-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-signed-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-signed-image-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1006-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1008-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1010-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1011-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1012-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1014-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1016-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-5.0.0-1018-azure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-azure' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.0.0-25 linux-headers-5.0.0-25-generic linux-image-5.0.0-25-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-25-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1020* linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1020* linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1020* linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1020-azure* linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1020-azure*
  linux-headers-5.0.0-1020-azure* linux-image-5.0.0-1020-azure* linux-modules-5.0.0-1020-azure* linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1020-azure* linux-tools-5.0.0-1020-azure*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 10 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
After this operation, 234 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 342406 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1020-azure (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
Removing linux-azure-cloud-tools-5.0.0-1020 (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
Removing linux-headers-5.0.0-1020-azure (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
Removing linux-azure-headers-5.0.0-1020 (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
Removing linux-tools-5.0.0-1020-azure (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
Removing linux-azure-tools-5.0.0-1020 (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
Removing linux-buildinfo-5.0.0-1020-azure (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
Removing linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1020-azure (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
Removing linux-image-5.0.0-1020-azure (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
I: /vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-29-lowlatency
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-29-lowlatency
I: /vmlinuz is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-1016-aws
I: /initrd.img is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-1016-aws
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-1020-azure
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-1016-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-1016-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-29-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-29-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-25-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
Removing linux-modules-5.0.0-1020-azure (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
(Reading database ... 315975 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for linux-modules-5.0.0-1020-azure (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing linux-modules-5.0.0-1020-azure, directory '/lib/modules/5.0.0-1020-azure' not empty so not removed
Purging configuration files for linux-image-5.0.0-1020-azure (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-1020-azure (5.0.0-1020.21) ...
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99095/discussion-on-question-by-biep-switch-to-azure-disables-mousepad-internet-usb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you ran some wrong command like `apt install linux*` that installed all kinds of wrong kernels.

You can remove the `azure` kernel by running

```
sudo apt purge 'linux.*azure'
```

You can also remove `kvm` by

```
sudo apt purge 'linux.*kvm'
```

The `gcp` kernel will be removed by

```
sudo apt purge 'linux.*gcp'
```

You will be shown the packaged to be removed with a prompt. You'll be able to check that `generic` is not there.

To make sure the generic kernel is there and will get updates, run

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

before a reboot.

Also I see you have `aws` and `lowlatency` kernels that should also be removed the same way.